# Phone validation with Other Phone Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am creating custom rule in Validate PLugin of Jquery with one mroe jQuery plugin. I am using jQuery plugin `https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input` to format phone number. I am including the rule in validate plugin like this.

```
$("#UserSettingsForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "data[User][phone]": {
                required: true,
                 fieldPresent: function () {
                     return $("#UserPhone").intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
                 }
            }
        },
    });
```

This returns the `$("#UserPhone").intlTelInput("isValidNumber");` true /false if number is valid. But its not attaching to element "data[User][phone]", Is thr a way I can attach it to the element without mentioning ID so that I can use it globally As well it validate my plugin using Phone validation as well.

Comment: Why not just use JQuery Validation plugin over that? It is built in and super simple to use and you can do custom validation for a phone number.

Comment: That won't provide me validation for all country of the world. It provide me validation along with format including ISD Code.

I just wish to add custom rule for the validation plugin.

Comment: I have done a couple custom rules before for the plugin, and I have found some of them to be clunky while upgrading versions of JQuery, just beware that if you write and extension or use someone's extension, after you upgrade JQuery Validater plugin you might have issue's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/validator/#jquery-validator-addmethod()) function of the library:

```
$.validator.addMethod('isValidNumber',function (value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || $(element).intlTelInput('isValidNumber');
},'Please specify a valid phone number');
```

Then your rules would look like this:

```
rules: {
    required:true,
    isValidNumber:true
}
```